# Validating several objects at once, before saving

Tags: django, django-models, sum

Is it possible to sum values in fields of several objects?

`class MyModel(model.Models): name = models.Charfield() amount = models.IntegerField()`

| Model |
| --- |
| Object 1 |
| Object 2 |
| Object 3 |
| Object 4 |
| Object 5 |

Here i want the sum of "amount" in all the objects to use in my validation. If the total "amount" is correct, i want to save all objects.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by creating a method (function in class) in the same model.

```
MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def sum_of_all_amounts(self):
        return (amount_1 + amount_2 ...)
```

you can call this function in the templating language by `{{ MyModel.sum_of_all_amounts }}`.
If you want to validate saving the model by the total amount then you can update the same function or make a method in which you can raise `ValidationError` if the total amount doesn't satisfy your needs.
If you don't know how to do that then you can ask me again by commenting on my answer.